# Regular Expression separation

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to make a regular expression that will select only the first string of two strings.

**IE:**

```
hello:howareyou
```

I want the regex to return only `hello`.

Similarly, I would want another one to return howareyou, but I should be able to figure that out once I understand the first part.

Thank you!

---

### EDIT:

So far I have tried `(?:[^"<:]|"[^"]*"|<[^>]*)*`  but that merely splits the two.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: That's way too complex for the example you give; it looks like it's parsing HTML tags. If your problem is as you stated, you need to worry only about these things: start of string, any number of non-colons, colon. The "any number of non-colons" needs to be captured. All the quotes and angle brackets is noise. Also, @Radu is quite correct that it is a bit too simple a job for a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `explode(':', $str)`, but if you insist on using a regular expression, you can do that as well with `preg_match('/(.+?):(.+)/', $str, $matches)` which will return the first part in `$matches[1]` and the second part in `$matches[2]`.